# Why am I receiving a SyntaxError: invalid syntax regarding the use of an elif statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying write a code which generates a series of responses: if the user enters 1 number, several numbers or a string instead in order to generate a list of Fibonacci numbers. The code is as follows:

```
def fib (a, b):
    return a + b

number = int(input("Please write how many Fibonacci numbers you wish to have generated: "))

fibonacci_list = []
for n in range(number):
    if n in [0, 1]:
        fibonacci_list += [1]
        print("The first", number, "Fibonacci number is:", fibonacci_list)
    elif:
        fibonacci_list += [fib(fibonacci_list[n-2], fibonacci_list[n-1])]
        print("The first", number, "Fibonacci numbers are:", fibonacci_list)
    else:
        print('Sorry could not recognise the input')
```

Comment: Else if *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a condition for `elif` too, for example:

```
elif n in [1,2]:
```

In your case, i would write the code in this way:

```
def fib (a, b):
    return a + b

try:
    number = int(input("Please write how many Fibonacci numbers you wish to have generated: "))

    fibonacci_list = []
    for n in range(number):

        if n in [0, 1]:
            fibonacci_list += [1]
            print("The first", number, "Fibonacci number is:", fibonacci_list)
        else:
            fibonacci_list += [fib(fibonacci_list[n-2], fibonacci_list[n-1])]
            print("The first", number, "Fibonacci numbers are:", fibonacci_list)
except:
    print('Sorry could not recognise the input')
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your elif is missing.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you miss a condition in your `elif`, but I highly recommend using `sets` in this case

```
if n in {0,1}:
    ...
elif n in {1,2}:
   ...
```

---

`sets` have better lookup time than lists. Also, [this is what they were meant for](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

> Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries.

Comment: _In general, I agree._ , _In this case - literally doesn't matter._ seems to me like contradictory statements. Why wouldn't someone learn how to do things the right way even if no _performance gain_ is apparent ?